# Regular expression for numeric order of the array

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want change order of parameter files of many simulation input files. Due to lots of material data files, (>100 materials@>200 lines) so i need to automation.

For example,

```
....
mobility = [1470.0 530.0],
eps0     = [3.0     -1.0],
....
```

to

```
....
mobility = [530.0 1470.0],
eps0     = [-1.0     3.0],
....
```

in this case, simple scripts form is best.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with a regular expression. They can't do numeric comparisons. I suggest you use an `awk` script.

Comment: I assume you're trying to reorder the parameters so they're in numeric order, not just swap the two numbers on every line.

Comment: If you just want to swap the two numbers, use capture groups and backreferences. Please show your attempt.

Comment: How I can write swap awk script?

Comment: Put the two numbers into variables. Then compare them so you can write them in numeric order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
cat tst.awk 
match($0, /\[[^]]+\]/) {
  str = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
  split(str, a)
  $0 = ( a[1] <= a[2] ? $1 OFS $2 " ["str"]," : $1 OFS $2 " ["a[2] OFS a[1]"]," )
  printf("%-8s %-1s %-6s %8s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input 
mobility = [530.0 1470.0],
eps0     = [-1.0     3.0],
```

For further reading, please have a look at [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).